# CASE ReGex with substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a SQL query where I am taking the substring of 2 names (First name/last name) to create an initials column, the data is unstructured to a certain extent (Can't show for GDPR reasons) but where there is a company name it is just in the surname column.

I'm trying to use Regex to say when the already present initials column is 1 letter (I.e not an initial) and if it is not an initial run a command that I wrote which successfully works.

```
CAST(CASE
     WHEN [DATA_TABLE].[INITIALS] = '\d' THEN (CONCAT(substring([DATA_TABLE].[FIRSTNAMES],1,1),substring([DATA_TABLE].[SURNAME],1,1)) AS char) AS INITIALS
        ELSE [DATA_TABLE].[INITIALS]
        end as char) as INITIALS,
```

An example of the data format:
First name     last name                   initials 
John           smith                       JS
               Electrical company          E 
Sam            Craig                       SC

I want the names that are just in the surname (Company names) to just remain as they are with no change (I.e The \d regex). Ones which don't will become the substring of their first name as (1,1) and a substring of their last name to also be (1,1).

Comment: . . I think you should really provide sample data and desired results to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: I advise against (re)using regex syntax to express any of this, seeing as how SQL Server has no support for them at all and `LIKE` patterns are only distantly related. Using regex syntax will raise false expectations and will almost inevitably encourage people to write things that won't work. If you want or need full regex support, use a CLR assembly.